# Plotting with different spacing for y-axis labels in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

I am trying to create a barchart using gnuplot. My requirement is that I should be able to label y-axis as 0, 1, 100, 10,000 (i.e., each tick increases by a factor of 100, except between 1 and 0). Also, this is not log-scale as I want this to start at 0. Let me know if you know how to do this.

Comment: Good question,  I too would like to know if an "exponential interval" can be specified for tics - without having to specify every tic explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set xtics`:

```
gnuplot> set xtics ("0" 1, "1" 2, "100" 3, "10000" 4)
gnuplot> plot "test.dat" notitle with boxes
```

produces the following plot:

http://marco.uctleg.net/resources/sample_xtics.png

with the following data:

```
1 12
2 8
3 19
4 42
```

EDIT: Just noticed you asked to change the y-axis. It's much the same, I'm sure you can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Marcog's answer is probably the best way to get exactly what you want,

However, if you don't want to do the reassignment of 1 means "0", 2 means "1" etc,
then you could try a simple

```
set ytics (0,1,100,10000)
```

To set the tics where you want them,
and then use the set format y to specify the format of the tics.

For example

```
set format y "10^{%L}"
```

to put the tics in nice exponential form (note this particular formatting looks pretty in postscript output, but rather ugly in the default gnuplot window).

See http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/tics-e.html for more on the set format command (midway down the page).

All the best